# What is "Error in SQL Launcher" means when using Dataflow SQL UI?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I tried to create a Dataflow job using the Dataflow SQL UI. I followed the [Using Dataflow SQL Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/dataflow-sql-intro) and the job ran properly. I changed the data source to a BigQuery table. My plan is:

1. Query from the BigQuery table
2. Save the result back to a BigQuery Table.

When I creating the dataflow job, I got the error message:
[Error in SQL Launcer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuXWv.png)

What does the error mean? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Question: if you need to query a table and save the results to another table, why dont you use the BigQuery engine instead of Dataflow engine?

Comment: Thanks for the question, @rmesteves. Yes, you're right. Using BQ engine is the best solution for my plan. But, I just want to learn how to use Dataflow SQL. Is my case plan can't be applied using Dataflow SQL?

Comment: Sure, you can use Dataflow. May you share your query? I would like to see what is going on. Also, can you let me know whether you are using a native table or an external table?

Comment: I used native table. I have a partitioned BQ table as data source (named by table_name_2). table_name_2 represent daily search number of cars. My schema are:
- **date_partitioned_edited**: date for partition
- **date_edited**: search date
- **cars_type**: type of cars
- **count_search**: search number

My query:
```
SELECT
    date_edited, SUM(count_search) AS count_search
FROM
    bigquery.table.`my-gcp-project-name`.dataset_name_2.table_name_2
GROUP BY date_edited
```

Is there any missing part about [sql lexical](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/sql/lexical)?

Comment: Your query seems right. What about the type of count_search field?

Comment: Integer. Do you think my error caused by java template execution at start?

Comment: @UmarSahid It should work when you don't select a Date field. We're investigating why it fails with a date field. If you're just playing around with Dataflow SQL, then would you keep experimenting without selecting a Date field and see if that works?

Comment: I just realized that the DATE type is not supported yet (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/sql/data-types). There was a bug in the SQL validator that didn't catch that.

Comment: SUPERB!! Thanks @PeterKim. I drop the `date_edited` column in the `SELECT` query, change it with `cars_type` and sum `count_search` column. It works!

Comment: Also thanks to @rmesteves for your attention to this issue

Comment: @PeterKim how to make your comment marked as answer? I'm also new in stackoverflow hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataflow SQL does not yet support the DATE type (there was a bug in the SQL Validator that didn't catch that). Selecting a field with DATE type will cause that NPE error message, and the fix is to only select fields that are [supported](http://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/sql/data-types).