# Error in SQL Launcher (java.lang.NullPointerException) in Google Dataflow SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, google-dataflow

I am trying to read the data from a Pubsub topic using Google dataflow SQL and getting "NullPointerException" error. Could anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong.

Below is the SQL query. I tried selecting few columns also. Same error is coming.

```
SELECT  tr.* FROM pubsub.topic.`project-xxx`.county_timeranges as tr
```

Log from LogsExplorer

```
logger: "com.google.cloud.dataflow.sqllauncher.DataflowSqlLauncher"
message: "Error in SQL launcher"
exception: "java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.mapTypeAnnotations(TypeAnnotationParser.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl.<init>(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory.buildAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.buildAnnotatedType(TypeAnnotationParser.java:79)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAnnotatedReturnType0(Executable.java:633)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotatedReturnType(Method.java:648)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.FieldValueTypeInformation.hasNullableReturnType(FieldValueTypeInformation.java:173)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.FieldValueTypeInformation.forGetter(FieldValueTypeInformation.java:132)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.AutoValueSchema$AbstractGetterTypeSupplier.get(AutoValueSchema.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.utils.FieldValueTypeSupplier.get(FieldValueTypeSupplier.java:43)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.utils.JavaBeanUtils.lambda$getFieldTypes$0(JavaBeanUtils.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.utils.JavaBeanUtils.getFieldTypes(JavaBeanUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.AutoValueSchema.fieldValueTypeInformations(AutoValueSchema.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.CachingFactory.create(CachingFactory.java:52)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.FromRowUsingCreator.fromRow(FromRowUsingCreator.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.FromRowUsingCreator.apply(FromRowUsingCreator.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.FromRowUsingCreator.apply(FromRowUsingCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubSchemaIOProvider$PubsubSchemaIO.<init>(PubsubSchemaIOProvider.java:176)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubSchemaIOProvider$PubsubSchemaIO.<init>(PubsubSchemaIOProvider.java:165)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubSchemaIOProvider.from(PubsubSchemaIOProvider.java:124)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubSchemaIOProvider.from(PubsubSchemaIOProvider.java:91)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.meta.provider.SchemaIOTableProviderWrapper.buildBeamSqlTable(SchemaIOTableProviderWrapper.java:72)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.meta.provider.datacatalog.DataCatalogTableProvider.buildBeamSqlTable(DataCatalogTableProvider.java:123)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.meta.provider.FullNameTableProvider$TableNameTrackingProvider.buildBeamSqlTable(FullNameTableProvider.java:163)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.BeamCalciteSchema.getTable(BeamCalciteSchema.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.jdbc.SimpleCalciteSchema.getImplicitTable(SimpleCalciteSchema.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteSchema.getTable(CalciteSchema.java:289)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.calcite.v1_20_0.org.apache.calcite.jdbc.CalciteSchema$SchemaPlusImpl.getTable(CalciteSchema.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.TableResolution.resolveCalciteTable(TableResolution.java:57)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.SqlAnalyzer.addTableToLeafCatalog(SqlAnalyzer.java:326)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.SqlAnalyzer.lambda$createPopulatedCatalog$1(SqlAnalyzer.java:216)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:407)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.SqlAnalyzer.createPopulatedCatalog(SqlAnalyzer.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.ZetaSQLPlannerImpl.rel(ZetaSQLPlannerImpl.java:98)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.ZetaSQLQueryPlanner.convertToBeamRelInternal(ZetaSQLQueryPlanner.java:168)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.ZetaSQLQueryPlanner.convertToBeamRel(ZetaSQLQueryPlanner.java:156)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.BeamSqlEnv.parseQuery(BeamSqlEnv.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand(SqlTransform.java:135)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand(SqlTransform.java:86)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:542)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:493)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:56)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:186)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sqllauncher.DataflowSqlLauncher.buildPipelineOrThrow(DataflowSqlLauncher.java:177)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sqllauncher.DataflowSqlLauncher.buildPipeline(DataflowSqlLauncher.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sqllauncher.DataflowSqlLauncher.buildAndRunPipeline(DataflowSqlLauncher.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sqllauncher.DataflowSqlLauncher.main(DataflowSqlLauncher.java:73)
```

Comment: The error similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811375/what-is-error-in-sql-launcher-means-when-using-dataflow-sql-ui), is there a field with a DATE type?

Comment: @JohnMichaelG- I already referred to that question. In my table, I don't have "DATE" column. String, Int64 and timestamp(pubsub eventtimestamp) columns are available in my table